# Allow Editors to run ImportCommandController in TYPO3 6.2

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

In an extbase extension, I have an ImportCommandController class that imports data. 
(See [In an extbase extension, how to access the persistence layer from a scheduler task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23068053/in-an-extbase-extension-how-to-access-the-persistence-layer-from-a-scheduler-ta))

In `ext_localconf.php`, it is hooked with

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['extbase']['commandControllers'][] = 'NAMESPACE\\Thekey\\Controller\\ImportCommandController';
```

On my server, cron jobs are a bit unreliable, they're often killed by a task killer. So I would give editors the possibility to start this Import manually when needed.

AFAIK, editors can't access the scheduler to start the task manually. So I guess I have to create a BE Module with a "do this" button, right? And how would that task be launched from there?

Comment: Euh... I think you already answered your own question. If you don't know how to create a BE module, kickstart 1 with the ext. builder will give you a good start.  Once you have done that, just copy your iport code and add it to the BE controller action.

Comment: I've got the module now. Don't know where to add the controller action yet. Can you point me to a tutorial? PS I would like to to call the existing class to avoid double code, if possible