# typo3 ignores storagePid

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I try to build an importer with a scheduler task.

The task creates an object manager which creates my import service.
This import service has dependencies to the repository.

I simply create instances and add them to the repository.

It works well until i tried to specify on which pid my records are supposed to be saved. I tried to configure it in setup.txt.

```
plugin.tx_extkey {
    view {
        templateRootPath = {$plugin.tx_extkey.view.templateRootPath}
        partialRootPath = {$plugin.tx_extkey.view.partialRootPath}
        layoutRootPath = {$plugin.tx_extkey.view.layoutRootPath}
    }
    persistence {
        storagePid = {$plugin.tx_extkey.persistence.storagePid}
        classes {
            EXTNAME\EXTNAME\Domain\Model\MODELNAME {
                newRecordStoragePid = {$plugin.tx_extkey.persistence.storagePid}
            }
        }
    }
    features {
        # uncomment the following line to enable the new Property Mapper.
        # rewrittenPropertyMapper = 1
    }
}

module.tx_extkey {
    persistence < plugin.tx_extkey.persistence
}
```

But that didn't work. Everything is still saved to pid `1`.

Are there any pitfalls that I might have overlooked?

Comment: pid 1 looks like the cast from the string, rather than a page ID. Therefore I suspect that the variable is not set.

Comment: another possible reason could be the wrong plugin - "tx_extkey" is actually "tx_extkey_pluginname" - so if you use multiple plugins make sure that you configure the stuff for the right plugin (that was actually my problem ;-) ) - full documentation is here: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/b-ExtbaseReference/Index.html

Answer (score 1):

I found an ugly way. The BackendConfigurationManager does not get the extensionName when the service is executed though the scheduler. Manually setting it in the task resolves this.

```
$objectManager = GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManager');

/** @var BackendConfigurationManager $configurationManager */
$configurationManager = $objectManager->get('TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Configuration\BackendConfigurationManager');
$configurationManager->setConfiguration(array(
    'extensionName' => 'hnsenvionjob'
));
```

Answer (score 0):

I use an ImportCommandController as recommended by lorenz in [In an extbase extension, how to access the persistence layer from a scheduler task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23068053/in-an-extbase-extension-how-to-access-the-persistence-layer-from-a-scheduler-ta/23279799#23279799) (my actual code has changed in the meantime, let me know if you want it)

and I have to set the pid manually:

`$item->setPid($storagePid);`

Answer (score -1):

There is an easy trick for that

add in your ts something like that

```
plugin.tx_extkey.settings.storagePid = {$plugin.tx_extkey.persistence.storagePid}
```

That will allow you to have access to your storage pid everywhere in your code where you have access to your ts. For example in controller

```
$this->settings['storagePid']
```