# Extend fe_users table with an extension in TYPO3 and user update not work

Tags: repository, typo3

I've extend the table `fe_users` with an extension in TYPO3.
I've implement a form in the frontend where user can add the own company.
And when I tried to update the `user` object (with the CRUD `$repository_user->update($user)`) nothing happened.

I've mapped the `TCA` with the new fields and in the backend the new fields are visible. What can I have forgotten?

No error messages, simply nothing happens.

Comment: Where are you call the `UserRepository->update`? Do you have maybe an "exit" or "die" after that?

Comment: In the controller. In the updateAction. There is no exit, die or something else. I've added the company to the object (works (output with var_dump to check)) and the userRepository->update($user) ... nothing happen

Comment: Is the company a relationship to an other domain model? Is the mapping of TCA for the model in the correct? Or is it only a string field?

Comment: Is it possible that the storagePID be a problem? It's another id as the pageid.

Comment: In backend everything works (create User, add company...) only in frontend not working

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the persistent manager to persistent all entities like in this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/23077743/2327734

Try also to inject the repository if not yet done so.

Answer (score 0):

**This answer is related to an `extbase`-implementation only**

The model for your new field might be missing.
You've to create an own model for `fe_users`, that can extend the existing model resided in `typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Domain/Model/FrontendUser.php` but is usually extended by namespace, so the code would be like this:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Domain\Model;

class FeUser extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FrontendUser
{

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    $myNewField = ''; /* in Database: `my_new_field` */

    // optional some more code ...


    /**
     * Sets the myNewField value
     *
     * @param string $myNewField 
     * @api
     */
    public function setMyNewField ($myNewField )
    {
        $this->myNewField = $myNewField;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the myNewField value
     *
     * @return string
     * @api
     */
    public function getMyNewField ()
    {
        return $this->myNewField;
    }

}
```

If you never chose to extend the existing model, you need to include getter- and setter-functions for all fields that might be somehow concerned in context of your own implementation (for some field-types further functions are required).

If your new field has a connection to another table or even represents a node of an mm-connection the model has to be adjusted accordingly, I just entered a simple example.